# получить все подгружаемые части html страницы

Tags: html, python, selenium

Занимаюсь парсингом сайта с помощью selenium и языка python. В самом низу страницы есть кнопка "показать еще", при нажатии на которую подгружаются еще данные к этой странице. Как выделить эти подгружаемые части для раздельного анализа? или может весь документ без разбиений. Иначе всё начинает виснуть и селениум не дожидается, выкидывает исключение драйвера (использую chrome).

У кнопки такой код

```
<button class="c-button" data-action="subscribe.more" data-type="userfollowers" data-id="471681968174531231" data-key="gdqXJ8OK9OZY-f0fdznafjGTq7K4niIVBRlezR80kvkyS6zvOGSVz_ktQA44VkDSo6boqgkHkVB35aVTM1lKKii3xSXIcg7QPp_WPNvAEbHQzkZmp1q4SIOWM7wBzvJ27UQ7c3u9FC-qWvcAr76nrFntkSlhTespa7TDZ0V528M">Показать ещё</button>
```

Comment: Ну вы к примеру через find_elements_by..() находите строки которые вам нужны, "запоминаете" их количество, нажимаете кнопку "показать ещё" снова делаете find_elements_by..(), и с разницей работаете. Это вероятно самый простой метод работы в такой ситуации.

Comment: так он с каждым разом будет снова "искать" то, что уже "находил" и новое сверху, всё равно будет сильно напрягаться. Но спасибо, я попробую так. Не подскажите пожалуйста, как работать с разницей? Допустим, я собрал 

links = find_elements_by(...)

Comment: @SovaKefirov почему у вас все начинает виснуть и какое исключение бросает селениум? Можете в вопрос добавить код?

Comment: @Sova Kefirov делаете первый `find_element_by..()`, он к примеру находит 21 элемент, то есть по индексам это будут 0-20 элементы, после "показать ещё" делаете снова `find_element_by..()`, который к примеру сейчас найдёт 42 элемента по индексам 0-41, но вы то уже знаете, что 0-20 это индексы старых элементов, значит 21-41 это индексы новых элементов

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую